# How do I get unique values from this array in PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, unique

Why is the code below returning `$null`? I'm trying to store just unique values.

```
$DailyPathsToDelete = @("C:\temp\IMG000483\","C:\temp\IMG000483\")
$DailyPathsToDelete = Select-Object $DailyPathsToDelete -Unique
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try :

```
$unique = $DailyPathsToDelete | Get-Unique
```

Answer (score 14):

**Short answer:**

To get all unique paths, you should pipe `$DailyPathsToDelete` to `Select-Object` and set the `Unique` switch.

```
$DailyPathsToDelete = $DailyPathsToDelete | Select-Object -Unique
```

**Longer answer:**

***1. Why it's not working***

After running your script `$DailyPathsToDelete` equals `$null` because (in the second line of your script) `$DailyPathsToDelete` is bound to the parameter `Property`. The parameter `InputObject` of the `Select-Object` cmdlet was **not speficified**, which is why the result of the invocation of `Select-Object` is `$null`.

This can be easily verified by tracing your expression:

```
Trace-Command -psHost -Name ParameterBinding { Select-Object $DailyPathsToDelete -Unique}
```

gives:

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Select-Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [True] to parameter [Unique]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to     [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [True] to param [Unique]     SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Select-Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [System.Object[]] to parameter [Property]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.Object[]] to param [Property] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Select-Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

***2. How to fix it***

Using `Select-Object`:

```
$DailyPathsToDelete = $DailyPathsToDelete | Select-Object -Unique
```

Using `Sort-Object`:

```
$DailyPathsToDelete = $DailyPathsToDelete | Sort-Object -Unique
```

***3. How NOT to fix it***

I would advise against using `Get-Unique` in your scenario since Windows local file systems (NTFS, FAT and variants) are case insensitive.

Example:

```
$DailyPathsToDelete = @("C:\temp\IMG000483\","C:\Temp\IMG000483\")
PS C:\> $DailyPathsToDelete | get-unique
C:\temp\IMG000483\
C:\Temp\IMG000483\
```

Answer (score 5):

1. With Get-Unique, gotcha - Get-Unique is case-sensitive and you also have to sort the list first!

   `$DailyPathsToDelete = $DailyPathsToDelete | Sort-Object | Get-Unique`
2. With Select-Object

   `$DailyPathsToDelete = $DailyPathsToDelete | Select-Object -Unique`
3. With Sort-Object

   `$DailyPathsToDelete = $DailyPathsToDelete | Sort-Object -Unique`

Comment: Actually, Select-Object is also case-sensitive. Example: `"temp","Temp" | select -unique` returns two items, not one.

Comment: Also, with Get-Unique one must use the -CaseSensitive parameter to Sort-Object: try this -- `"abc", "Abc",  "def", "abc" | sort -Case | Get-Unique` -- with and without it and you get different results!

Comment: @msorens You're absolutely right. Funny, I actually reported this behavior to the PowerShell team in 2011 and now it's now added to the help topics.